# Installed 18.04 Server and netplan was NOT installed

Tags: dns, netplan

Installed 18.04 on an older Dell server.  Netplan was not installed nor was the /etc/netplan directory created.  I attempted to update the /etc/network/interfaces file with the DNS nameservers (I used google's) but the machine still cannot resolve.  Because I cannot resolve, I cannot update or install packages.  I attempted to install Netplan.io from a .deb file but that didn't work either.  Can someone please give me a hand here.  I am stuck with a new server install and I can't do a thing with it.  Thank you all

```
interfaces:
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 10.0.10.245
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.10.0
        broadcast 10.0.10.255
        gateway 10.0.10.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 10.0.10.1 8.8.8.8
        dns-search premprovsol.com
```

Shawn Simmons

Comment: Can you at least ping the 8.8.8.8 ? You could also insert picture of your configuration file.

Comment: I'm curious how you managed to install Ubuntu Server without netplan.io. I cannot find any supported install path for 18.04 that does not include it.

Comment: Me too.  I've actually installed the server 4 times and each time nada

Comment: John, yes - google, foxnews, etc.  All by ip address though.

Comment: Try to add google dns server into /etc/resolv.conf file.